I don't know the value returned to me when testing bloc in Flutter
Im developing an app on Flutter. I want to test bloc using mockito but I don't know response. (status code:200 but response is a very big and dynamic model)
I read the same example in every source, I don't understand. Please help me, Thank you.
blocTest<DataBloc, DataState>(<br/>
      'emits [loading, data] when API call is successful',<br/>
      build: () {<br/>
        when(mockApiService.get(any)).thenAnswer(<br/>
          (_) async => http.Response('{"data": "sample data"}', 200),<br/>
        );<br/>
        return dataBloc;<br/>
      },<br/>
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(FetchDataEvent()),<br/>
      expect: () => [<br/>
        DataState(loading: true), // İlk loading durumu<br/>
        DataState(data: '{"data": "sample data"}'), // Başarılı yanıt<br/>
      ],<br/>
    ); <br/>


In build you can put function for preparation you do before starting test.
"I don't know response." Create response that you expect. Use it in this part: (_) async => http.Response('{"data": "sample data"}', 200),
If any other question you have, write it more specific. What exactly you don't understand.
If you don't know what you want to know, read documentation : https://bloclibrary.dev/testing/
